# ¿Como puedo realizar diferentes acciones acorde el webdriver que elija?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Como esta escrito en el codigo tengo 2 webdrivers (Firefox y Chrome) y cada vez que se abre el script se elije el webdriver a ejecutar de manera aleatoria. Lo que quiero realizar es que: 
Si se abre Firefox vaya a facebook.com
Si se abre Chome vaya a google.com

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
# Generated by Selenium IDE
import pytest
import time     
import json
import pandas as pd 
import autoit   
import random      
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

drivers = (driverfirefox(), driverchrome())
driver = random.choice(drivers)()

def driverfirefox():
        driver = webdriver.firefox()
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
driverfirefox()

def driverchrome():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.ar")
driverchrome()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque tu implementación es una posibilidad de hacer lo que quieres, comentes unos cuantos errores:

- Defines tu tupla `drivers` antes que las funciones `driverfirefox` y  `driverchrome`, por lo que en ese momento no existen aún, lo que desencadena en un `NameError`.
- Tu tupla `drivers` debe contener referencias a las funciones no su retorno. Al hacer:

  ```
  drivers = (driverfirefox(), driverchrome())
  ```

  estás ejecutando ambas funciones y su retorno (`None`) se agrega a a tupla. Al final no hay nada de aleatorio (primero se ejecuta `driverfirefox` y luego  `driverchrome`) quedando la tupla en todo caso como:

  `drivers = (None, None)`
- Además, llamas a las funciones después de definirlas. Esto las ejecuta también secuencialmente con lo que, de nuevo, nada de aleatorio hay.
- Por último, tienes un error tipográfico en `driver = webdriver.firefox()`, debe ser `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`.

La idea es que `drivers` contenga solo referencias a las funciones que quieras llamar de forma aleatoria. `random.choice` te retorna una referencia aleatoriamente y luego llamas a la función gracias a ella:

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver


def driverfirefox():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

def driverchrome():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.ar")

drivers = (driverfirefox, driverchrome)
random.choice(drivers)()
```